# Spark DataFrame save as parquet - out of memory

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using spark to read a file from s3, then I load it to a dataframe and then i try to write it to hdfs as parquet.
The thing is that when the file is big (65G), and for some reason I get out of memory...in any case I have no idea why I get the outof memory because it looks like the data is partitioned pretty well.

this is a sampel of my code:

```
val records = gzCsvFile.filter { x => x.length == 31 }.map { x => 

   var d:Date = Date.valueOf(x(0))

      //var z = new GregorianCalendar();z.getWeekYear   

    var week = (1900+d.getYear )* 1000 + d.getMonth()*10 + Math.ceil(d.getDate()/7.0).toInt 
    Row(d, Timestamp.valueOf(x(1)), toLong( x(2)), toLong(x(3)), toLong(x(4)), toLong(x(5)), toLong(x(6)), toLong(x(7)), toLong(x(8)), toLong(x(9)), toLong(x(10)), toLong(x(11)), toLong(x(12)), toLong(x(13)), toLong(x(14)), toLong(x(15)), toLong(x(16)), toLong(x(17)), toLong(x(18)), toLong(x(19)), toLong(x(20)), toLong(x(21)), toLong(x(22)), toLong(x(23)), toLong(x(24)), toLong(x(25)), x(26).trim(), toLong(x(27)), toLong(x(28)), toLong(x(29)), toInt(x(30)),  week)
}
var cubeDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(records, cubeSchema)
cubeDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).partitionBy("CREATION_DATE","COUNTRY_ID","CHANNEL_ID" ).parquet(cubeParquetUrl)
```

does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: 65GB isn't very big - how much memory do you allocate for executors?

Comment: About 20GB.
Keep in mind that right now I am testing it under yarn.

Comment: It might be that a single parquet file will need more memory (before compression). I constantly see that interim stages require much more memory than original file sizes

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8890

Parquet's memory consumption when writing output out is substantially larger than we thought. In the soon-to-be-released Spark 1.5, we turn to sorting the data before writing a large number of parquet partitions out to reduce memory consumption.